# Why is this validation code not working?

Tags: javascript, validation

I looked over my code and changed it and everything looks alright I just dont understand why it is not working!  When I open it in my browser and enter a phone number and press the button nothing happens.  It does not alert me like I want it to.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Number Validation</title> 
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("valButton".onclick=validateIt;
}

function validateIt(){
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
        {
    alert("Yay it's a phone number!");      
    return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("Not a valid number");
        return false;
        }
}
</script>
<p>Phone Number Validation:</p>
<p>Enter a phone number here:<br>
    <input type="text" size=30 id="phoneno" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Validate" id="valButton" />
</p>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Why the Java tag? What does this question have to do with programming in Java? I've removed this tag, please correct me if wrong.

Comment: How would it work, the function is never called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues:

1- The function is never called

2- The function has a syntax error

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt) {
    var pattern = "/^\d{10}$/",
        phoneno = new RegExp(pattern);
  if (inputtxt) {
     if(inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
         return true;
      } else {
        alert("message");
        return false;
      }
   }
}
//Using jQuery for DOM manipulation you can execute the function on validate button click
$('#valButton').on('click', function () {
    var phoneInputValue = $('#phoneno').val();
    phonenumber(phoneInputValue);
});
```

Checkout fixed code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/au7aft0k/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add an `"onblur=phonenumber()"` to your input, to trigger calling the function when control leaves the input (click or tab away).

Answer (score 0):

The function you have written never gets executed.  You need to add an event handler onto the button and/or the input itself.  The easiest way to do so is after the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires (DOM has been parsed).

```
var btn = document.getElementById( 'valButton' );
btn.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var txt = document.getElementById( 'phoneno' ).value;
  if ( phonenumber( txt ) ) {
   alert( 'Test passed. Do stuff here' );
  } else {
   alert( 'Test failed!!' );
  }
}, false );
```

Similarly if you want to automatically check after the person leaves the input field you would use:

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'phoneno' );
input.addEventListener( 'blur', function(){
  if ( phonenumber( input.value ) ) {
   alert( 'Test passed. Do stuff here' );
  } else {
   alert( 'Test failed!!' );
  }
}, false );
```